# Unable to find xml element

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xpath

I'm trying to parse and read an xml with xml.etree.ElementTree (I can't move to lxml) but I've been unable to.

XML: https://pastebin.com/yJqAW0L0

```
<GetResponse xmlns="http://mywebsite.com/myservice/">
    <AutoScalingGroup>
        <AutoScalingGroupName>foo</AutoScalingGroupName>
        <AttributeValuePair>
            <Attribute>owner</Attribute>
            <Value>bob</Value>
        </AttributeValuePair>
    </AutoScalingGroup>
</GetResponse>
```

I've tried doing

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET.register_namespace('', "http://mywebsite.com/myservice/")
NSMAP = {'service':'http://mywebsite.com/myservice/'}
tree = ET.fromstring(page) # This is where i grab the xml from
autoscalingGroups = tree.findall('.//service:AutoScalingGroup', namespaces = NSMAP)
for asg in autoscalingGroups:
    name = asg.findtext('.//service:AutoScalingGroupName', namespaces = NSMAP, default = "Default asg name")
    print "asg name: " + str(name)
```

This doesn't return anything and I'm struggling to find why.

1) how do i get 'foo'?
2) how do i get 'bob'?
Am i using the wrong XML xpath?

Comment: Are you trying to interact with the AWS API without using a supported library?

Comment: not really - the names of the elements were just for the example (i might rename them to avoid confusion)